# ValueError: Cannot assign "username'": "Comment.created_by" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a comment to a model and I'm getting a ValueError when i try to call the User model. I don't know what I am doing wrong, here are my code snippets

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Comment(models.Model):
    *****
    *****
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_comment(request, course_slug, lesson_slug):
    data = request.data
    name = data.get('name')
    content = data.get('content')
    course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)
    lesson = Lesson.objects.get(slug=lesson_slug)
    comment = Comment.objects.create(course=course, lesson=lesson, name=name, content=content, created_by=request.user.username)
    return Response({'message': 'Comment added successfully'})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ****
    ****
    path('<slug:course_slug>/<slug:lesson_slug>/', views.add_comment),
]
```

> [17/Sep/2022 12:37:52] "OPTIONS /api/v1/courses/python-programming/lesson-one/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
> Internal Server Error: /api/v1/courses/python-programming/lesson-one/
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
> return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
> response = self.handle_exception(exc)
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
> self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
> raise exc
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
> response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\courses\views.py", line 41, in add_comment
> comment = Comment.objects.create(course=course, lesson=lesson, name=name, content=content, created_by=author)
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
> return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 451, in create
> obj = self.model(**kwargs)
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 485, in **init**
> _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
> File "E:\Web Projects\Learning Management System\src\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 215, in **set**
> raise ValueError(
> ValueError: Cannot assign "'jacob.zulu@cs.unza.zm'": "Comment.created_by" must be a "User" instance.
> [17/Sep/2022 12:37:52] "POST /api/v1/courses/python-programming/lesson-one/ HTTP/1.1" 500 119197

Comment: you have to use `created_by_id` instead `created_by` when you referring it to Foreign Key

Answer (score 0):

Change your views like this,

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_comment(request, course_slug, lesson_slug):
    data = request.data
    name = data.get('name')
    content = data.get('content')
    course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)
    lesson = Lesson.objects.get(slug=lesson_slug)
    comment = Comment.objects.create(course=course, lesson=lesson, name=name, content=content, created_by=request.user) # updated here
    return Response({'message': 'Comment added successfully'})
```

Since `created_by` is an FK you need to pass the user object, not the `user.username`

```
comment = Comment.objects.create(course=course, lesson=lesson, name=name, content=content, created_by=request.user)
```

Comment: Hello @Rahul K P,  

So when I the user object it gives me another error  

    django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'created_by_id' in 'field list'")

Comment: Have you called makemigrations, and migrate command with manage.py ?

Answer (score 0):

```
comment = Comment.objects.create(course=course, lesson=lesson, name=name, content=content, created_by=request.user)
```

`created_by` must be a `User` object, not a string. so try to provide the `User` object here.